# Why is the ratio in the number of degrees in a diatomic molecule 3:2:1 instead of 3:3:3?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why is the number of degrees of freedom in a diatomic molecule not three in the case of the rotational (in middle of the picture below) and the vibrational mode (the lowest part of the picture below), just as in the velocity mode? Each velocity can be broken up in three base velocities, but can't the same be said for the vibrations and rotations? Any vibrational mode, for example, can just as velocity be broken up in three base vibrations, so it seems to me. Where am I wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The theory would will have three rotational modes, but one of the modes will be at much higher energy than the rest, due to the tiny moment of inertia about the symmetry axis.

The energy goes as $T=\frac 12 \omega^2 I$ and the angular momentum is $L=\omega I$. As angular momentum comes in discrete quanta $L=n\hbar$, such that $\omega=L/I=n\hbar/I$. Substituting this into the energy equation we get

$$ T = \frac12\frac{L^2}I = \frac12\frac{n^2\hbar^2}I $$

So if the $I$ for one axis is really small compared to the others, this rotational mode will be of much higher energy, and thus frozen out of the dynamics.

As for the vibrational mode, in a Diatomic molecule you can choose your coordinates such that the only relative motion between the molecules is radial (i.e. 1 dimensional) it thus makes scene that there is only one vibrational mode. For tri-atomic (and higer) molecules, the situation is different and you can have many more modes active.

Comment: @MikaelFremlingI didn't mean the rotation around the atom-atom axis, but a third rotation around the y-axis (in the figure above), which has the same energy as the other two. Every rotation has components in the x-, y-, and z-axis, like the velocity. As far as the vibrational modes concerns, you can use the same argument as for the velocity. You choose the coordinates such that the motion relative to these is one-dimensional. The other molecules though don't have this property, like the vibrational mode. A random vibration is relative to a coordinate system built up out of three base .

Comment: vibrations. And besides that, a vibration is also related to the direction of velocity (the two atoms have opposite velocities), so why don't these velocities have three degrees of freedom too? Do you understand what I mean? :-)_

Comment: @descheleschilder: Yes there was a typo in the displayed equation. Fixed now.

Comment: @descheleschilder: I'm unsusre what you mean when you say "a third rotation about the y-axis". There will be one rotational component around each of the x,y,z axis, it's just that one of them has a much higher energy that needs to be exited (it will be activated if the temperature is large enough).

Comment: As for the vibration, there really only is one degree of freedom here. Imagine you had a vibration where the molecules moved perpendicular to the direction joining them. This situations does not cost any energy and hence there is no restoring force, and hence no vibratinal mode. What you are actually seeing is one of the rotations you have already acounted for.

Comment: @MikaelFremling-When I say rotation around the y-as I mean the same kind of rotation as the other two, but around the axis perpendicular to the other two axes.So not the frozen rotation. Regarding vibration: What if the molecule moves colinear with one of the other two axes? Vibrating in thát direction costs energy and isn't accounted for by the depicted vibration. above. Just like moving in only one direction doesn't account for the other two directions, vibration in one direction doesn't account for the other two directions of vibration: The vibrations collinear with the other two axes.

Comment: That third (high energy) rotation mode only exists classically. The quantum system doesn't even have that in the absence of some external interaction breaking the rotational symmetry about that axis.

Comment: I see my error now. I changed in my head the directions of the depicted molecules above. You mustn't do that to count the number of degrees. If for example, I rotate the molecule 90 degrees around the vertical axis, you essentially arrive at the same situation, and in the case of rotations, there are again two possible degrees of freedom and only one for the vibration.

Comment: @dmckee-Do you mean that n=0 for that rotation in the quantum case?

Comment: @MikaelFremling-If you treat the two depicted rotations quantum mechanically too isn't their energy bigger as in the case of the frozen rotation, due to the low value of n for the frozen rotation? I is bigger for the two depicted rotations but isn't n (which goes quadratically) larger?